# Pixealted text in print outs when using window.print()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using window.Print() to print the content on a web page. The page has an image and a heading which is in arial, sans-serif and 30px.

When I take the print out the heading comes out very pixelated and when I check the same in browser it looks smooth and good.

How can I improve the quality of the text that is being printed?

[image: Browser]
[image: XPS]

Comment: When I verify the same as an XPS document the text is pixelated, so, there is no way its the printers fault.

Comment: If you provide XPS screen + screenshot from browser, it would be easier to guess.

Comment: "The page has an image and a heading which is in arial, sans-serif and 30px." You mean that the text is in the image ? In that case it's probably the image resolution that is too low.

Comment: What browser are you using? Does this happen on every browser?

Comment: No on all the browsers its coming fine and smooth. By the way we are using IF8 and Firefox for testing.

Comment: @Beniot - No the text is not a part of the image. It's in a div tag.

Comment: The screenshots that I have added with this question is somehow not getting displayed.

Comment: Well, I can suggest checking print settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem as I've never witnessed this before but have you tried setting the font size in points in a print stylesheet?

```
 @media print {
    body {
        font-size: 24pt;
    }
}
```

As I say, I doubt this is it but it's worth a shot.

Comment: In your question you said you specified the font as 30px. Are you saying you have now tried it using pt instead and that hasn't worked?